# How to specify a generic type should implement another generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, where-clause

Imagine the following method

```
public void SomeMethod<T>(T param)
    where T: List<T2>
{
}
```

It doesn't work:

> Error  16  The type or namespace name 'T2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I achieve the what I clearly intended to do?

Comment: What you intend to do is not clear because your title is worded improperly. It should be: "How to specify a generic method to take a parameter that is a generic type?".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to do this, you need to specify an additional generic parameter

```
public void SomeMethod<T1,T2>(T1 param)
  where T1 : List<T2>
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As a side answer to the accepted solution, since T is explicitly related to T2, why have T at all?

```
public void SomeMethod<T2>(List<T2> listParam) 
{
}
```